# Perché non sento il verbo "ribadire" nelle conversazioni informali?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, formal

Volevo sapere se il verbo "ribadire" ha un utilizzo più formale che informale. Perché lo sento più nella TV o lo leggo nei giornali piuttosto che sentirlo nelle conversazioni informali?

Comment: A mio avviso è proprio come ipotizzi tu.

Comment: Come mai hai cancellato, la risposta, @Charo? Mi sembrava utile.

Comment: Già, @Charo, il dizionario di De Mauro non conferma appieno l'intuizione dell'OP, ma mi sembra una fonte autorevole sul fatto che, in ogni caso, la parola “ribadire” appartiene a un registro lievemente superiore al corpus “fondamentale” identificato da De Mauro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il *Grande dizionario italiano dell’uso* di Tullio De Mauro fa la distinzione, nella sua sezione ["Marca d'uso"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6), tra queste e altre categorie:

> **FO**: fondamentale; tra i lemmi principali, sono così marcati i vocaboli di altissima frequenza, le cui occorrenze costituiscono circa il 90% delle occorrenze lessicali nell’insieme di tutti i testi scritti o discorsi parlati; 
>   **CO**: comune; sono così marcati i vocaboli che sono usati e compresi indipendentemente dalla professione o mestiere che si esercita o dalla collocazione regionale e che sono generalmente noti a chiunque abbia un livello mediosuperiore di istruzione;

Esempi di parole con la marca "FO" sono "famiglia", "giorno" o "questo" nelle loro accezioni più comuni. Esempi di vocaboli con la marca "CO" sono "allusivo", "prevalenza" o "odierno". Molti dei termini marcati con CO, come questi esempi, appartengono a un registro un po' più elevato 
(come si indica sopra, possono persino essere sconosciuti a un parlante che non abbia un livello di istruzione mediosuperiore) e non sempre sono sentiti come adatti a una conversazione informale (non tutti, però, perché la marca CO in realtà sta a indicare che sono vocaboli molto meno frequenti nell'insieme di "tutti i testi scritti o discorsi parlati" di quelli marcati con FO). Il verbo ["ribadire"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ribadire) nella accezione figurata

> ripetere, riaffermare con decisione o, anche, avvalorare, riconfermare con nuovi argomenti o prove: *ribadire un’affermazione, un concetto, un’accusa*

ha la marca d'uso "CO" ed è di solito avvertito come un vocabolo un po' ricercato, cosa che spiega perché non è tanto usato in contesti colloquiali informali.

Comment: Quindi dalla tua risposta devo dedurre che un parola definita come "comune" è generalmente capita solo da chi ha un livello scolastico medio superiore?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Non ho detto questo.

Comment: E io non ho detto che tu l'hai detto (con "dire" nel senso di "sostenere"). Però, se capisco semanticamente l'Italiano, mi sembra che sia il dizionario da te citato che lo sostiene. E, detto fra parentesi (non voglio attirarmi le ire dei sapientoni), la definizione data non mi sembra accurata.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Neanche il dizionario dice questo.

Comment: Allora per favore me lo spieghi tu?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Il dizionario dice: se un parlante ha un livello di istruzione mediosuperiore probabilmente conoscerà una parola marcata come "CO". Se un parlante non ha questo livello di istruzione può conoscere o può non conoscere quella parola. E non stanno dando una definizione di "comune", stanno dicendo: quando abbiamo marcato una parola con "CO" vogliamo dire questo.